# Why does setting the template for the product description remove the entire product tabs?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am following a course where the task was to change the template forthe product description:

**etc/frontend/di.xml**:

```
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description">
    <plugin name="product-view-desription-plugin"
  type="Training\Test\Block\Product\View\Description" sortOrder="10"/>
```

**Block/Product/View/Description.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Training\Test\Block\Product\View;

class Description extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description $originalBlock) {
      //Set a new tempalte
      $originalBlock->setTemplate('Training_test::description.phtml');
  }
}
```

**view/frontend/templates/description.phtml**

```
<h1>Custom description template!</h1>
```

However when I view the page the product tabs are gone (Bonus points where is the error message for this layout breakage?)

[image: missing-product-tabs-magento-2]

Comment: Sigh, the `$originalBlock->setTemplate('Training_test::description.phtml');` module name is not correct should be: `Training_Test`...it now works. Bonus points still up for where template error goes.